# transmission on old /home to new install

Tags: permissions, bittorrent, transmission

ubuntu mate 20.04.3 LTS, transmission 2.94

wiped my root and installed new ubuntu and mounted on to old home.

Now whenever i start transmission it defaults to an old list of torrents which need to be verified individually to each location i've since moved it to, and needs to verify each file every time i restart the program.  If i remove a torrent, it comes back on restart.

I can add new torrents and it is able to start download, which tells me it has read/write access.

checking .config/transmission files, it has create/delete files for folder access for both owner and group [username]

I tried moving my old transmission folder from a backup manually after a complete removal and reinstall but it returns to the same problem.  only thing that piques my interest is that my current (and backup) resume folder has twice as many files as the torrent folder.

I'm running out of ideas.

edit: just ended up deleting and re-adding all the torrents again manually.  seems like if moving the profile folder doesn't work there's no other way around it.

Comment: When you reuse an old `/home` partition on a new installation sometimes you need to get rid of the old configs. Try to back up and delete `~/.config/transmission` including files and subfolders.

Comment: tried that, including uninstalling and reinstalling transmission.  replacing with old configs gives the odd problems as described above.

Comment: Best to ask this on the Transmission support site.

Comment: post is already there but no answers so far haha.

Comment: You can also check `~/.cache/transmission` .

Comment: cache only has icons